# Can private hashing techniques be used in MySql 2000 server ? Help me decode this?

Tags: sha-1, md5

So last night my father gave me my birthday challenge. He made a website and asked me to get admin access there. I don't have any XSS knowledge, so I started with SQL Injection. I tried using SqlMap but couldn't understand anything.
I looked for something on HackForums and a guy there gave me something called SQLi Dumper. I used that with some asp.net link of the website and its DBs got open. I was very happy. It seemed too easy. 
I opened the table containing the admins and exported the data their.
Again everything looked too easy the table names were obvious. 
But when I opened my exported data it gave the pass like this:

Now its been 7 hours since I've trying to find out what this crap is and I thing I m gonna die soon. SO help me figure out this.
Is it possible that he made his own hashing algo?
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Remove hold , question edited.

Comment: I noticed and I'm sorry to say so, but after your edit it is now unclear what exactly you're asking (since the ciphertext was the core of the question). All that's left is a "how can I crack something I'm not mentioning"… rendering it into an "unclear what you're asking" kinda thing which – again – is off topic. Since you're new to our site (welcome btw) you might have not yet have checked [our help center](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help) which (among other things) describes [what questions we handle at Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Hope that helps…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start from another end. Probably, your father used some CMS to create this website. And most likely, it's open source. You can download it, install it and analyse what happens inside and, as a result, to get a hint what exactly is stored in the DB and how.

Comment: I checked it already its actually a basic asp sites. No cms is used there.

Comment: Is there anyway I could find out which encryption was being used by the particular column.